# Failure while building apk in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

whenever i try building a apk i get this error. I have enabled multidex and androidx
Tried clearing the cache using flutter clean and yet i get this error

```
Note: C:\Joel\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_android-2.0.9\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\pathprovider\PathProviderPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key upload from store "C:\Joel\AndroidStudioProjects\sudoku\upload_signing.jks": Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 9s
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Android Studio and go to `File > Settings > Build, Execution, Development > Build Tools > Gradle`, then change Gradle JDK to jdk16, then click Sync Gradle.

Hope this work's.

Comment: i dont see it... i can only see a tick box saying generate iml files and a dropdown for property gradle home